# Use Qt-based lib in gtk framework

Tags: qt, gtk, program-entry-point, bridge

We're trying to find out how I can use the Qt code we wrote in a gtk-based application.  Rumour has it that adapters are possible, [in less than 600 LoC](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2006/02/24/qt-and-glib/), but apparently all links lead to web pages covered in 6 years worth of dust.

So here's the question: how can I create a `QCoreApplication` that uses the gtk main loop?

Comment: I think `QCoreApplication` uses a Glib main loop internally. I've never done it myself, but I think the pattern is to create a `QCoreApplication` and use its `exec()` method, which will run the Glib main loop, too.

Comment: @StefanMajewsky, apparently only on Linux?

Comment: @ptomato: Probably yes. On Win/Mac, Qt will probably try to integrate with the system libraries' event loop to support native API calls.

Comment: Building Qt with glib with a mainloop is a build-time configuration flag. I don't know if it's enabled in most builds or not